# Draggable range slider for touch screen

Tags: html, css

I am creating a slider using range.Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YELP/)

html :

```
<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="1" max="90" value="1" >
```

css

```
 input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
       -webkit-appearance:none !important;  
       width:15%;
       height:40px;       
        border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -wekkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border:1px solid black;
        background:#FFFFFF ;

     }
```

It is working fine in pc. But in touch screen when i want to drag its thumb its not working. Can anyone tell me why it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding jquery mobile to the head tags for the touch screen to work. More information is available at jquerymobile.com.

Comment: I think you want me to use jquery slider?

Comment: No try adding jquery mobile. It includes the touch gestures so it's going to work.

Comment: Did you try the jquery mobile slider?  Or try hammer.js. You can use it without jquery even though a jquery version is also available. Here is the link http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/ .